# Swift: map enum values to types at compile time

Tags: ios, swift

I've got an enum in a library target. Like this:

```
enum SomeEnum {
  case EnumValue1
  case EnumValue2
  case EnumValue3
}
```

I've got some structs in my app. Like this:

```
struct Struct1 {...}
struct Struct2 {...}
struct Struct3 {...}
```

My aim to map this structs to enum values in my app at compile time.
Something like this:

```
extension SomeEnum {
  case EnumValue1(Struct1)
  case EnumValue2(Struct2)
  case EnumValue3(Struct2)
}
```

But apparently I can't add associated values in an extension.

Original enum in a library shouldn't know anything about my app structs. I'd like to perform this mapping on the app side. So I can't modify my original enum. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** Sorry, I've missed a use case example. I want to create an object of corresponding struct type for each enum value:

```
func createStruct<T>(type: T.Type) {
  return T()
}
```

Usage:

```
let enumValue = SomeEnum.EnumValue2
//here I should use an invented way of mapping enum value to struct:
let object = createStruct(enumValue.struct)
```

Comment: Could you explain how you will use this mapping?

Comment: @mixel I have added necessary information to my question.

Comment: is this still not possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Qute from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_632)

> the raw-value type must conform to the Equatable protocol and one of
>   the following literal-convertible protocols: IntegerLiteralConvertible
>   for integer literals, FloatingPointLiteralConvertible for
>   floating-point literals, StringLiteralConvertible for string literals
>   that contain any number of characters, and
>   ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible for string literals that
>   contain only a single character.

even if you try to realize `Equatable` protocol - it won't work.

```
struct Struct1 : Equatable {}

func ==(lhs: Struct1, rhs: Struct1) -> Bool {
    return true // some code here
}

enum SomeEnum {
    case EnumValue1 = Struct1
}
```

This code won't work. Maybe you should create some `String` that will match your struct.

UPD: You can use associated values like it's said in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID147). And it will be during compilation not runtime.

```
struct Struct1 {}
struct Struct2 {}
struct Struct3 {}

enum SomeEnum {
    case EnumValue1(Struct1)
    case EnumValue2(Struct2)
    case EnumValue3(Struct3)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for concern. My initial idea was to implement it with associated values, not raw values. Yes, it's not possible with raw values for reasons provided by you. My question is not about raw or associated values. It's more general: how can we map enum values to types at compile time? Yea, it would be simple with a dictionary of type [SomeEnum:Any.Type] or something like this, but it would be a runtime mapping.

Comment: @slashdot seems that understood you right now, look at my update.

Comment: Thank you, it's much closer approach :). But as I mentioned, enum is in an independent library, and structs are in an app linking with this library. Thus enum should be unaware of struct types. So I'm searching for a way to add this mapping without initial enum modification. And it's seems that it's not possible at the moment :(.

Comment: @slashdot it's not `objc-c`, where you can add or map your own methods and swizzling during runtime =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
extension SomeEnum {
    func getStruct() -> Any.Type {
        switch self {
        case .EnumValue1:
            return Struct1.self
        case .EnumValue2:
            return Struct2.self
        case .EnumValue3:
            return Struct3.self
        }
    }
}

let structType = SomeEnum.EnumValue1.getStruct()
```

But it seems useless because you do not know type of `structType` and have to use `switch...case` again to determine it.